# How to subscribe to an Observable and extract from an Object an Array of values

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a template that looks like this.

```html
  <ng-container *ngIf="contactList$ | async as contactList">
    <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="contactList">
      <ion-item *virtualItem="let c" (click)="openProfile(c)">
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <img [src]="c.profilePicture" />
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label position="stacked">{{ c.lastNames }}, {{ c.firstNames }}</ion-label>
        <ion-label position="stacked">{{ c.mutualFriends[lastNames] }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-virtual-scroll>
  </ng-container>
```

and depending on how I modify the subscription to an observable depends on weather or not I can see the Object of an Array's sub Array. In this example `c.mutualFriends[name]` is a sub Array that has additional information. `mutualFriends` is an Array of Objects (an example is below).

now in the component I was previously doing:

```js
    this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe((users: Contact[]): void => {
      this.contactList = users;
    });
```

*side note: I know that with this way you need to alter the template above in order not to get errors. in this case delete the `<ng-container>`*

When getting the values this way the array of strings in `c.mutualFriends[lastNames]` will be listed. after subscribing to the observable this way:

```js
this.contactList$ = this.contactService.getContacts();
```

inside the template the `c.mutualFriends[lastNames]` nothing is listed.

How can I render from the example below:

```
contact = {
  lastNames: 'Garcia Smith',
  firstNames: 'Gabriel',
  mutualFriends: [
    {
      lastNames: 'Llull',
      firstNames: 'Ramon',
      mutualFriends[],
    },
    {
      lastNames: 'Pereira dos Santos',
      firstNames: 'Joāo Maria',
      mutualFriends: [],
    }
  ],
};
```

in my template I want to see `'Llull, Pereira dos Santos'` like I could with the first way of subscribing.
I hope this was enough detail. thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the other infos shown? I.e.: does `c.profilePicture` outputs something? If you try to output the entire response as `{{contactList | json}}` or `{{c | json}}`, do you get something or an empty object?

Comment: yea all the rest of the info is shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `subscribe()` method. As `subscribe()` method is used to activate observable and to listen emitted values by observable.

```
this.contactList$ = this.contactService.getContacts()
    .subscribe((users: Contact[]) => {
      this.contactList = users;
    });
```

In addition, you have a choice to use `pipe()` operator. `pipe()` operator is used for chaining observable operators

```
this.contactList$ = this.contactService.getContacts()
    .pipe(
         map((res) => {      
             this.contactList = res.json();
         })
     );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I thought that I could do it the simpler way since it is just fewer lines, but, sometimes there is just no getting around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `ngFor` to loop through the array

```
<ng-container *ngIf="contactList$ | async as contactList">
    <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="contactList">
      <ion-item *virtualItem="let c" (click)="openProfile(c)">
        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
          <img [src]="c.profilePicture" />
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label position="stacked">{{ c.lastNames }}, {{ c.firstNames }}</ion-label>
        <ion-label position="stacked" *ngFor="let mutualFriend of c.mutualFriends">{{ mutualFriend.lastNames }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-virtual-scroll>
  </ng-container>
```

You have to loop through the array and display the prams you want

Comment: thanks this works, I thought I could do something like this but I was hoping to get around _another_ for loop _inside_ a loop makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the values 'lastNames' from the array of objects 'mutualFriends' for more details,

[From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 0):

mutualFriend is an array so you need to access the elements using index and not with string.

Try using:

c.mutualFriends[index].lastNames

where index is the loops index or use static values as 0,1...

Or You need to run loop on mutual friends to access all elements of mutual friends.